# Read last line of text file after FileSystemWatcher detects change

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I am new to c# so please forgive my ignorance, I am running a fileSystemWatcher on a text file. And it is working fine, I can do some simple tasks after the file has changed. All but what I want to do.
I am trying to read the last line of the text file that has changed with this code

```
public void File_Changed( object source, FileSystemEventArgs e )
{
    string MACH1 = File.ReadText(@"C:\MACHINE_1.txt").Last();
    if (MACH1=="SETUP")
    {
        MACHINE1IND.BackColor = Color.Green; 
    }
    else
    {
        MACHINE1IND.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    }
}
```

It works fine inside a button but not after file watcher.
Says it cannot find file?

Comment: Can you put in some more detail about what you mean by *inside a button but not after file watcher*? Maybe some more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of is that the FSW can issue multiple change notifications during a save operation. You have no way of knowing when the save is complete. As a result, you need to always wrap your code in a try..catch block and support retry after a timeout to allow the file write to be completed. Typically, I will try to move the file to a temp location where I will do my processing. If the move fails, wait a couple seconds and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check if the file exists before accessing it.

```
public void File_Changed(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    string filePath = @"C:\MACHINE_1.txt";
    if(!File.Exists(filePath)) //Checks if file exists
        return;
    string MACH1 = File.ReadText(filePath).Last();
    if (MACH1=="SETUP")
    {
        MACHINE1IND.BackColor = Color.Green; 
    }
    else
    {
        MACHINE1IND.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jim Wooley explains in his answer, the file operation might still be in progress, when FSW fires a `Created` or `Changed` event. If FSW is used to communicate between two applications and you are in control of the "sending" application as well, you can solve the problem as follows:

Write the information to a temporary file. Close the file. Rename the temporary file and give it a definitive name.

In the other application (the receiver) watch for the `Renamed` event using the `FileSystemWatcher`. The renamed file is guaranteed be complete.